# android studio Image upload still send same image even not selected

Tags: android, image-uploading

No issues in send the upload image android using volley but the problem comes when the first image upload the i click upload button the same images will upload again even not selected but still send the previous images. If the first image selected upload and choose another images to upload no issues.

using volley and mysingleton to send data.

this is ImageUpload.java

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ImageUpload extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/demonuts";
private Button buttonUpload, buttonChoose;
private ImageView imageView;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private final int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_upload);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);

    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonChoose:
            showPictureDialog();
            break;


        case R.id.buttonUpload:
            uploadImage();
            break;
    }
}

private void showPictureDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
    String[] pictureDialogItems = {
            "Select photo from gallery",
            "Capture photo from camera" };
    pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            choosePhotoFromGallary();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            takePhotoFromCamera();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    pictureDialog.show();
}

public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY);
}

private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {

        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri path = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), path);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(ImageUpload.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        saveImage(bitmap);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(ImageUpload.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
    // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
    if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    try {
        File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[]{f.getPath()},
                new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
        fo.close();
        Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());

        return f.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

private void uploadImage(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.URL_UPLOAD,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String Response = jsonObject.getString("message");
                        Toast.makeText(ImageUpload.this,Response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        imageView.setImageResource(0);
                        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("image",imageToString(bitmap));

            return params;
        }
    };

    MySingleton.getInstance(ImageUpload.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}

private String imageToString(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] imgBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
}
}
```

this is php file to retrieve the post image just for testing use random name only.

```
$response = array();
$name = rand(1,10);
$uploadpath = "../upload/$name.jpg";


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
if(empty($_POST['image'])){
  $response['error'] = true;
  $response['message'] = "Please choose images";
}else{
  $image = $_POST['image'];
  file_put_contents($uploadpath, base64_decode($image));
  $response['error'] = false;
  $response['message'] = "Image upload succesfully";
}
}else{
  $response['error'] = true;
  $response['message'] = "Please choose images";
   }

echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your method with this

```
@Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("image",imageToString(bitmap));
            bitmap=null;
           return params;
        }
```

& check before upload

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonChoose:
            showPictureDialog();
            break;


        case R.id.buttonUpload:
        if(bitmap!=null)
         uploadImage();
        else
        Toast.makeText(this, "add image first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```